# jQuery show extra field conditional on current input's value

Tags: jquery

Sorry to ask such a basic question. Say, I have two inputs. The first one is always visible, while the second shows up only when the first one's value is less than 0. I tried to use .change to implement this activity, however it does not work. So can anyone give me some suggestions? 
Thanks in advance.

HTML code:

```
<table>
<tr><th><label for="id_first">First input:</label></th><td><input type="text" name="First input" id="id_first" /></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_second">Second input:</label></th><td><input type="text" name="First input" id="id_second" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

jQuery code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src=" ../stylesheets/jQuery-1.7.2.js"></script> 

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#id_second').closest('tr').hide();
    $('#id_first').change(function() {    
    if ($(this).val() <0){
        $('#id_second').show()}    
    else{
        }
    });​​
```

Comment: You're hiding the row containing the input, and then trying to show the `input`, instead of the row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your jquery code should be as below. You had a syntax error. You did not close the change function, and you have to show "tr", not just the input element

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#id_second').closest('tr').hide();
    $('#id_first').change(function() {    
        if ($(this).val() <0){
            $('#id_second').closest("tr").show()
        }    
        else{
        }
    });
});​​
```

Comment: thank you for the correction. I think I forgot to add the "tr", which caused the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Please, use the length property when checking on the `if ($(this).val() <0)` condition

```
$('#id_second').closest('tr').hide();
$('#id_first').keyup(function() {    

if ($(this).val().length < 1){
    $('#id_second').closest("tr").show()}    
else{
        }
        });
​
```

(code by @dg3)

http://jsfiddle.net/chepe263/jPybT/3/

Comment: OP code is to check if the input value is a negative value. Not whether a value is existing or not

Comment: though it is different from what I asked, still teaches me how to validate inputs. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#id_second').parents("tr").hide();
     
     $("#id_first").keyup( function() {
        if((parseInt($(this).val(), 10)<0)){
            $('#id_second').parents("tr").show();}
        else {
            $('#id_second').parents("tr").hide();}
     });
});
```

[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NnQxh/1/)

`.val()` is getting `string`. You have to convert it to `integer` using `parseInt(string,radix)`.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my english. I think this solution have to work properly.

```html
<table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <label for="id_first">First input:</label>
            </th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="First input" id="id_first" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <label for="id_second" style='display:none'>Second input:</label>
            </th>
            <td>
                <input type="text"  name="First input" id="id_second" style='display:none'/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

<script>
        // Subscribe on keyup event in first input
        $('#id_first').on('keyup', function(){
            // here "this" refers to input in which we have press the key

            // Getting first input value
            var inputValue = this.value;


            // Casting input value to number
            // -12a became -12
            // a12 or any value starting from a character became 0 
            inputValue = parseFloat(inputValue) || 0;


            // Now we selecting input and a label which we want to show/hide
            var $second = $('#id_second, label[for="id_second"]');


            // Check if first one's value is less than 0 
            // and shows the second row, if it is
            if(inputValue < 0)
                $second.show();
            // Otherwise hides the second row
            else
                $second.hide();

        })

    </script>
```